# SSO with specific session timeout duration based on application

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, session-timeout, openiddict

We've implemented an **OpenIDConnect** Identity Server using **OpenIddict** to provide **SSO** across a number of existing legacy .NET WebForm apps as well as some newer Angular apps. The Identity server uses a session cookie with a sliding expiration so the user doesn't need to log in each time they access an app if they already have an active session on the Identity server.

We've been given a requirement that some of the legacy apps need to maintain their existing session timeout durations and they cannot all have the same session timeout as managed by the Identity Server. e.g. App A has a timeout of *1 hour* and App B has a timeout of *20 minutes*. When an app times out, it should not log you out of other apps.

Are there any known patterns/solutions for solving this type of problem? I think the Identity server will have to be notified each time a user times out on an application so it can then use this information to decide whether to prompt for login again next time the user is redirected by the application to re-authenticate. Could this work and are there any potential pitfalls to consider?